# Facebook oauth login with custom parameters using Sorcery gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, oauth, sorcery

I'm trying to pass a custom parameter to Facebook oauth url to get it back in the callback. I know it's possible but I'm using Sorcery gem and I need to set the parameter dynamically, I mean I can't define it in sorcery.rb initialization file, like it is now:

```
Rails.application.config.sorcery.configure do |config|
  config.facebook.callback_url = ENV['FACEBOOK_CALLBACK_URL']
 ...
end
```

I need to define in my controller, how can I do it with this gem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found this documented but it worked, so just put in your controller:

```
::Sorcery::Controller::Config.facebook.callback_url = ENV['FACEBOOK_CALLBACK_URL'] + "param1=foo"
```

and param1 will be send back to you after authentication :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `state` parameter outlined in [oAuth Dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/).

> A unique string used to maintain application state between the request
>   and callback.

Facebook will redirect back to the site with:

```
YOUR_REDIRECT_URI#
    access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN
   &expires_in=NUMBER_OF_SECONDS_UNTIL_TOKEN_EXPIRES
   &state=YOUR_STATE_VALUE
```